# Bounded non periodic solutions of ${\displaystyle {\dot {x}}=A(t)x}$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, dynamical-systems, periodic-functions

I am interested in the behaviour of the solutions of the  $2\pi$-periodic differential equation $${\displaystyle {\dot {x}}=A(t)x}$$ with

$$A(\text{t})\text{=}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sin (t) & \sin ^2(t) \cos (t) \\
 \sin ^2(t) \cos (t) & \cos (t) \\
\end{array}
\right);$$
I plotted for example the solution $x(t)=(x_1(t),x_2(t))$ with initial condition $x(0)=(x_1(0),x_2(0))=(0,1)$, where $x_1(t)$ is in blue and $x_2(t)$ is in red.

[[image: <span class=]$x_1(t)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIQA1.jpg)
[[image: <span class=]$x_2(t)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdYBJ.jpg)

It seems we have boundedness of all solutions on $(-\infty,\infty)$ and these solutions do not seem to be $2\pi$ -periodic. According to the table in [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Linear_system_of_differential_equations_with_periodic_coefficients) , boundedness of solutions are linked to characteristic exponents being purely imaginary with simple elementary divisors of the indicator matrix. Is there a method to compute the exponents?

**So my questions are**

**1) How to prove boundedness of all solutions on $(-\infty,\infty)$**

**2) How to prove that these solutions are not periodic.**

Comment: The equation is linear, so boundedness of all solutions follows from boundedness of any two linearly independent initial conditions. Something similar may work for periodicity.

Comment: @eyeballfrog what do you mean by boundedness of initial condition? an initial condition here is just a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Also solutions of linear equations can be unbounded in time.

Comment: Let me rephrase. If there are two linearly independent initial conditions that each produce a bounded solution, then all solutions are necessarily bounded. This is because all solutions are linear combinations of those two solutions, and the linear combination of two bounded solutions is bounded. This means your boundedness proof can just check the easiest two linearly independent cases.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the fundamental matrix $X(t)$, the solution of $X'(t) = A(t) X(t)$ with $X(0) = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr}$. Then $X(2\pi) = B$ where $$\det(B) = \exp\left(\int_0^{2\pi} \text{tr}(A(t))\; dt\right) = \exp(0) = 1$$
Numerically (using Maple's numerical DE solver)
$$ B = \pmatrix{0.736606947094663 & 0.310166738881922\cr -3.21321753950662 &0.00457171990219575\cr}$$
The characteristic polynomial of $B$ is
$$\lambda^2 - \text{tr}(B) \lambda + \det(B)$$
where, as above, $\det(B) = 1$ while numerically $\text{tr}(B) \approx 0.741178666996859$.  Since $\text{tr}(B)^2 - 4 \det(B) < 0$ the eigenvalues
are complex conjugates with absolute value $1$, say $\exp(\pm c i)$.  The fact that their absolute
value is $1$ shows that the solutions are bounded.
The solutions are non-periodic  if and only if $c$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$.  This is not possible to determine with certainty numerically, but if $c/\pi \approx 0.3791557842561098$ is  rational it does not have a small denominator: the continued fraction starts $[0; 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 7, 2, 2, 1, 1, 10, 3]$.